# "WebGoat" or DVWA analogs for web QA specialists

Tags: training

For security professionals there are practical applications for training ([WebGoat](https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat), [DVWA](http://www.dvwa.co.uk/) ). Is there a similar application for QA web testers?